# how to bind event in javascript using addeventlistner?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert `jquery code to vanila` js .I am facing issue in event bind .I am getting below error I found that  `:last-child` and `:last` is not valid in javascript.then what is the alternate ?
I am trying to add event listener, but I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '.u28result:last-child a:last' is not a valid selector.
        at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/aa/aa.js:1315:48)**
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$(".u28w8").on("keydown", ".u28result:last-child a:last", function (e) {
                            if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (e.keyCode === 9) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                searchresults.find('.u28resultsclose a').focus();
                            }
                        });
```

same thing I want to do in vanila js .Any way to bind event in `:last-child`  and `a:last` using js

```
  document.querySelector(".u28w8").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        function handler(e){
            if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9) {
                return;
            }
            if (e.keyCode === 9) {
                e.preventDefault();
                searchresults.querySelectorAll('.u28resultsclose a')[0].focus();
            }
        }
        for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
            if (target.matches(".u28result:last-child a:last")) {
                handler.call(target, e);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

I think there is something wrong in this line.

```
target.matches(".u28result:last-child a:last")) {
```

I am trying to add event through event delegation

how to bind event last child  with last a ?

Comment: There is a :last-child pseudo-class but no :last

Comment: well, because you're going for :last-child and :last, can't you just access the elements and then pick the last one from the resulting collection? Not everything has to be done with css selectors.

Comment: there is no Loop in the jQuery code, why i ther one in the vanila JS ?

Comment: @MisterJojo `$(".u28w8").on` implicitly loops (but given your answer, i think you know that)

Comment: I assume the loop was intended to check if the clicked element was a child of an element that matches the selector... I think at this point the better approach would be to abandon the jquery process all together and look at this as a fresh problem to be solved without jquery from the beginning.

Comment: @KevinB this loop belong to a JS `.forEach((el,_, A)` where A is the array of your loop

Comment: what is `searchresults` ?  by the way, it would be easier to understand if the PO gives us a preview of the HTML concerned

Comment: `:last` is a jQuery extension to selector syntax.